# Is there any limitation on Url's length in Android's WebView.loadUrl method?

Tags: android, webview

I want to "transfer" local resources to a page, loaded from remote server.

I want to do somthing like this:

```
webView.loadUrl('http://my.server.com/page.html');
webView.loadUrl('javascript:function someLong(){}function codeHere(){}....');
```

This is for saving a bandwidth and reduce loading time.

As i see, assets files can't be loaded from remote web page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is no limit or it is very large. I've done some tests with simple code

```
webView.loadUrl(
    "javascript:function a(s){alert(s.length + ' ' + s.substring(s.length-5))}");
String repeated = 
    String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", 80000), 0).replace("0", ".") + "xx";
webView.loadUrl("javascript:a('"+repeated+"')");
```

First line: define a function, second line - prepare long string, third one - call defined function with very long string argument.

It works perfectly. As a result i seeing JS alert saying: "80002 ...xx"

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html) `webView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");` only **calls** a JS methods, not inject them to HTML page. Maybe you want to use `webView.loadData()` or `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL()` methods? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make my probles more clear... I have a remote page. This page has JS code. Some code are mine, and i want to hold this code on Android side. Some code is not mine, it is some service which is loading data from network (images, additional js code). I want to reduce bandwidth useage by putting mine code to Android side and not to download it by the network. As i have remote code, which intercats with remote servers, i can't use webView.loadData() method and can't use file:///android_asset/ As a workaround i want to "transfer" my sources via LoadUrl("javascript:...") call.

Answer (score -1):

By default the loadURL makes a get request which is having a limit of 254 characters. That why the problem is.

Comment: I think you are wrong in GET request limit amount. As far as i know the GET request is limited to 2048 bytes. And where is no problems for now, i transferred about 2100 bytes throught loadUrl... But this is not meaning what there is no limit.